# Calculating Effective Maturity with Negative Cash Flows

Tags: finance, banking, debt, credit

The formula for [effective maturity](https://www.eba.europa.eu/regulation-and-policy/single-rulebook/interactive-single-rulebook/1604).

Suppose that an installment plan also shows additional borrowings of a debtor. That is, at some point in time **(other than the inception date)** the borrower is given a fixed amount for once or several times before the maturity.

To illustrate (assume that the inception date is the first day of 2023):

| Date | Payment/Loan | Payment/Loan Amount | Outstanding Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2024 | P | 10 | X |
| 01-01-2025 | P | 10 | X-10 |
| **01-01-2026** | **L** | **20** | **X+10** |
| 01-01-2027 | P | 13 | X-3 |
| 01-01-2028 | P | 13 | X-16 |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |

In that case, should the additional loans be taken into account as negative cash flows while calculating the effective maturity of the loan? That is;

[image]

or not

[image]